# Поиск корней квадратного уравнения через т. Виета

Tags: python, python-3.x

Требуется решить квадратное уравнение с помощью Теоремы Виета.
Вот что получилось у меня, но это не выполняет задачу правильно.

```
print("Значения ax^2+bx+c=0")
a = float(input("a = "))
b = float(input("b = "))
c = float(input("c = "))

def vieto(z,v,x):
    if a ** 2 != 0:
        x1 = -b/a
        x2 = c/a
        print(x1,x2)
    else:
        print("Нет корней.")

f = vieto(a,b,c)
print(f)
```

Comment: Какие числа Вы вводите, какие получаете и какие хотите получить?

Comment: и в чем, на Ваш взгляд, заключается теорема Виетта?

Comment: Ввожу такие числа: a=2,b=8,c=2. Хочу получить: -0.27, -3.73.

Comment: Не выполняет задачу правильно потому что вычисления в коде даже отдаленно не имеют отношения к теореме Виетта. Думаю, что вам нужно её перечитать. PS. Хотя не, чуток похоже.

Comment: @Sofanchik 1. Ваши корни округленные, потому как 'x1*x2 = 1.0071' , а не 1 ровно. 2. Функция принимает аргументы z, v, x, но нигде не использует их, а использует не существующие локальные a, b, и c.

Comment: @Pavel_K В любом случае выражения для x1,x2 не имеют прямого отношения к корням.

Answer (score 1):

```
def v(a, b, c):
    x1 = x2 = 0
    points = [i for i in range(-100, 100)]
    for i in points:
        x1 = i
        for j in points:
            x2 = j
            if x1 + x2 == -b / a and x1 * x2 == c / a:
                return x1, x2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    v(#Тут ваши аргументы)
```

Будет работать только для целых чисел.
Так же можете изменять range для того, чтобы увеличить зону поиска

Answer (score 1):

```
def drange(x, y, jump) -> float:
# Генератор чисел float
    import decimal
    while x < y:
        yield float(x)
        x += decimal.Decimal(jump)

def viet(a, b, c):
# Подбор корней по теореме Виетта
    D = (b**2 - 4*a*c)**0.5
    x1 = x2 = 0
    points = [i for i in drange(-5, 5, '0.001')]
    if D > 0:
        for i in points:
            x1 = i
            for j in points:
                x2 = j
                if round(x1 + x2, 2) == round(-b / a, 2) and round(x1 * x2, 2) == round(c / a, 2):
                    return x1, x2
    if D == 0:
        for i in points:
            x1 = i
            if round(2 * x1, 2) == round(-b / a, 2) and round(x1 ** 2, 2) == round(c / a, 2):
                return x1
    if D < 0:
        print('Корней нет!')


a, b, c = float(input('a = ')), float(input('b = ')), float(input('c = '))
print(viet(a, b, c))
```

Список корней points здесь от -5 до 5 с точностью до 0,001, т.е. 10000 вариантов. Увеличивая диапазон, возрастает и время выполнения перебора.